# Can a quadratic involving complex inputs be solved by the quadratic formula as well?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a quadratic equation $\gamma(z) = az^2 + bz + c = 0,$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R},$ takes as input values from the complex plane, may one use the quadratic formula to solve the quadratic equation? Won't these solutions necessarily involve complex numbers whose $y$-components are $0$, since the quadratic formula would be some algebraic expression of real numbers? Thank you!

$$az + b = cz^2 + dz \implies cz^2 + (d-a)z - b = 0$$

Applying the quadratic formula:

$$z = \frac{-(d-a) \pm \sqrt{(d-a)^2 + 4cb}}{2c}.$$

Would I leave the solution simply in this form?

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question, but one I think worth clarifying: are $a,b,c$ real numbers or complex numbers?

Comment: it works, but you may get the square root of a complex number and have no way to improve it.

Comment: Hey, Evee. Yes, thank you for asking. They are real numbers. I will clarify that in the post. :)

Comment: Hey, will! One would arrive at a complex number if the value in the square root is less than $0$ right?

Comment: @Ana There's no notion of less than that is canonical on the complex numbers. There are two roots to each complex numbers. Both are non-complex only if the number is a non-negative real.

Comment: Hey, Don. I edited by post. I am actually trying to address a more specific question. Is the solution I wrote to the given quadratic equation the simplest form that it can take? Or would your change the solution to say/look differently?

Comment: Yea, that looks about right.

Comment: @Ana I cannot think of something simpler.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: The form in which you leave a solution depends on a lot of things: are you being asked to leave the solution in some particular form? are you going to use the solution as an intermediate step in some longer problem?

Comment: For arbitrary a, b, c, d this is it.  Also the coefficients may be complex.

Comment: Hey, Gerry! No, im not asked to leave the solution in some particular form. Im simply asked to find the fixed points of a linear fractional map $\phi(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d},$ where $ad - bc = 1,$ $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}.$ If I assume the case where $c \neq 0,$ the equation written in my post follows, and the fixed points are precisely the solution to that quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular problem, if $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are all real numbers, there are three possibilities:

- The expression under the square root sign, $(d-a)^2 + 4cb,$ is a positive real number. Then you have two solutions for $z,$ both of which have zero imaginary component.
- The expression under the square root sign, $(d-a)^2 + 4cb,$ is zero. Then you have one solution for $z$ (also called a double root) and it has zero imaginary component.
- The expression under the square root sign, $(d-a)^2 + 4cb,$ is a negative real number. Then you have two solutions for $z,$ both of which have non-zero imaginary component, and both of which have the same real component.

In fact, in the third case the two solutions for $z$ will be what are called complex conjugates: the real component is the same and the imaginary component of one is exactly opposite the other.
The sum of the two solutions has zero imaginary component,
so also does the arithmetic mean of the two solutions (which is just half the sum).